# Why does external js only appear in header? D7, in a block, via custom module

Tags: 7, javascript, blocks

I'm trying to add a box.com file upload widget to certain pages in a block. The upload widget is an external js script. I'm adding it via a custom module, using hook_block_view,

```
switch ($delta) {
    case 'box_com_photo':
    $block['subject'] = t('Box File Uploads: Photography');
    $block['content'] = array(
        '#attached' => array(
        'js' => array(
            'scope' => 'content',
            'data' => 'https://app.box.com/embed/upload.js[custom widget code]',
            'type' => 'external',
          ),
        ),
      );
      break;
```

Regardless of the scope, it always shows up in the page header.

Suggestions??

Answer (score 1):

Content isn't a valid region for scope, it can only be header or footer. See this documentation: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7

The render process runs drupal_add_js/css based on items inside of #attached.

Comment: OK, but if I change the scope to 'footer' it still shows up in the header.

Answer (score 1):

[AdvAgg](https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg/) supports scripts in various regions. But the way you're trying to use is not supported (JS in a block).

In settings.php add this.

```
$conf['advagg_scripts_scope_anywhere'] = TRUE;
```

This allows for scripts to be put in any scope outside of the header and footer.

Anyway to answer you question I would put raw js with the script tags into the block.

```
switch ($delta) {
    case 'box_com_photo':
    $block['subject'] = t('Box File Uploads: Photography');
    $block['content'] = '<script src="https://app.box.com/embed/upload.js[custom widget code]" type="text/javascript"></script>';
      break;
```

I created [a feature request for this](https://www.drupal.org/node/2534864), since we want something similar here at my work.